# Date parsing from string to long gives wrong result

Tags: java, timestamp

I got simple code, maybe the problem relies on the given format string or on the timezone. So here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    try {
        Date added = df.parse("00:00");
        System.out.println(added);
        System.out.println(added.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result is:Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 EET 1970
-10800000 --> should be 0 as we give 00:00 hours in and the other time elements remain default.

**//Edit**

Yes the problem is with timezone to fix this use
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); before parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value 10800000 is exactly 3 hours (in milliseconds), which I'm gathering is roughly the offset between EET and UTC (actually, it's only 2 hours according to [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/eet.html), but I guess the extra hour's down to DST or something).

Therefore, the difference is probably due to your timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Your timezone appears to be EET. That difference would be the offset from 1st Jan 1970 00:00:00.000 UTC

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the date, only the hour, you actually created a Date object with default values, as specified in the [DateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) (which SimpleDateFormat implements):

> The date is represented as a Date object or as the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.